# Combine multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php

I have found several posts but none is working. Tried array_merge, array_replace_recursive, array_merge_recursive, but not serving my purpose.

I want to combine 5 arrays below into single array, but I don't understand why years are changing. Is it because of what documentation said:

> If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value
>   will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

```
<?php
$a['x'][2015]['s'] = "xxxxxx";
$a['x'][2015]['d'] = 1;

$b['x'][2014]['s'] = "yyyyyyyyy";
$b['x'][2014]['d'] = 3;

$c['x'][2013]['s'] = "sssssss";
$c['x'][2013]['d'] = 22;

$d['x'][2012]['s'] = "ddddddddddddd";
$d['x'][2012]['d'] = 21;


$f['x'][2011]['s'] = "ffffffff";
$f['x'][2011]['d'] = 52;


$e = array();

$e = array_replace_recursive  ($e,$a);
$e = array_replace_recursive  ($e,$b);
$e = array_replace_recursive  ($e,$c);
$e = array_replace_recursive  ($e,$d);
$e = array_replace_recursive  ($e,$f);

echo json_encode($e);   
?>
```

<del>Output I am getting
{"x":{"2015":{"s":"xxxxxx","d":1},"2016":{"s":"yyyyyyyyy"},"2017":{"d":3},"2018":{"s":"sssssss","d":22},"2019":{"s":"ddddddddddddd","d":21},"2020":{"s":"ffffffff","d":52}}}</del>

**EDIT: Sorry, array_replace_recursive gives correct result. I was doing something wrong in phpfiddle.org simulation ....**

Comment: How should output look like? Please, edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you. I've even executed your code (using `array_replace_recursive`) and have the following result:

```
{
    "x": {
        "2015": {
            "s": "xxxxxx",
            "d": 1
        },
        "2014": {
            "s": "yyyyyyyyy",
            "d": 3
        },
        "2013": {
            "s": "sssssss",
            "d": 22
        },
        "2012": {
            "s": "ddddddddddddd",
            "d": 21
        },
        "2011": {
            "s": "ffffffff",
            "d": 52
        }
    }
}
```

May be you did something else?
And yes, `array_merge_recursive` is not an option in this case.

Comment: oh, damn .. i think something is messed up in phpfiddle.org ....whatever I am changing, it is not changing output ...